# Manipulating Mongo Documents in Node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm building this project with the MEAN stack.

In my Mongo collection, my documents have following structure :
{_id,
artist,
album}

Each document must be unique and I'm letting mongodb figure out the Id incrementation as I add documents.

I access each document via a url with this structure :
http://server/#/vinyls/_id
so for example :
http://localhost:8181/#/vinyls/57dfe3aab482c58c46715fd2

Ok. I have read that using mongo Ids in urls isn't necessarily a bad thing.
What is making me worried is that I'm often using `new ObjectId` in my node application to fetch documents...

There is an example of this in the route to delete a vinyl :

```
app.delete('/vinyls/:id', function(req, res) {

    let vinyls = mongoUtil.vinyls(); // my Mongo collection
    vinyls.remove( {"_id": new ObjectId( req.param('id') ; // can't pass in the Id directly !
});
```

Would the correct way to do this be to program a simple integer counter for my document Ids instead of using the mongo Object_id ?

many thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The ObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) was designed to work with the distributed nature of MongoDB in mind, so you have a guarantee that even though there are multiple apps inserting into the database (where the database can also reside in multiple servers), you won't get a duplicate `_id`.

You can of course devise your own method to create a primary key for your database. If you are certain that you will never use more than one app inserting into the database, and if you can be certain that there won't be a duplicate `_id`, then it may be a reasonable solution for you.

However, please note that MongoDB does not provide an auto-increment primary key function like in most relational database. The main reason for that is because MongoDB was designed with [Replication](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/), [Sharding](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/sharding/), and horizontal scalability in mind. An auto-increment field will work if your database is always contained within a single server (like SQL). If your database is spread out across multiple servers, then you will need a single source of truth for the incrementing field, which could badly limit your insert performance.

**EDIT**

Remember that ObjectId is just a built-in solution if you insert data into MongoDB without providing an `_id` field. You can replace it with anything you want as long as you can be certain it will be unique.

For example, in your case, it might be feasible to use an md5 hash of the (artist + album) string, e.g:

`db.collection.insert({_id: md5(artist + album), artist: artist, album: album})`

which could provide a reasonably unique `_id`. The `_id` field in this case will contain an ordinary 32 character string.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is that I have to keep converting the numerical ID that is in my front end application to a mongo Object_id. There for I have to  new ObjectId(interger_id) all the time. Is there a way around that ?

Comment: You may be able to use a hash for the `_id` field. I updated the answer since it's too long to type in a comment.

Comment: No worries. Please accept the answer if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can update in that way . Just make sure that your  `req.param('id')` is same 24 character string of you `ObjectId`

Comment: You mean that I should just use the Mongo native Ids ? It forces me to instantiate ObjectId everytime I wan't to fetch a document, which feels clumbsy...

Comment: `ObjectId` is the mongo's default recommendation for _id. you can always override it my generating your own unique id and pass it for _id in your insert statement.  Meteor uses a string in place of ObjectId. 

You can write a wrapper that passes a unique string for _id for your insert call.